# c++ - sorting std::vector in pathfinding

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, path-finding

I'm trying to implement a rough pathfinding example into a game i'm working on. I'm at a point where I need to sort a `std::vector<Tile*>` and i've tried to do so with the following but I get a bunch of errors I can't figure out. I've also tried to change the references in the sortF struct to pointers, but I get another error - `Comparison between pointer and integer ('Tile *' and 'int')`.

The error in question is: `No matching function for call to object of type 'Stage::sortF'`

Wondering what exactly i'm doing wrong here.

(and if anyone had any comments on the pathfinding that would be good too)

in Stage.h public

```
struct sortF
{
    bool operator()(const Tile& a, const Tile& b) const
    {
        return a.f > b.f;
    }
};
```

in Stage.cpp

```
bool Stage::tilePath(Tile* start, Tile* end)
{
    std::vector<Tile*> path;
    std::vector<Tile*> open;
    std::vector<Tile*> closed;
    start->previousTile = start;
    start->g = 0;
    start->h = 0;
    start->f = 0;

    int i, j;
    float g, h, f;

    int sx, sy, ex, ey;

    int cost;

    Tile* current = start;
    Tile* neighbor = NULL;
    Tile* previous = NULL;
    std::cout << neighbor << std::endl;

    while(current != end) {
        sx = fmaxf(0, current->x - 1);
        sy = fmaxf(0, current->y - 1);
        ex = fminf(17 - 1, current->x + 1);
        ey = fminf(6 - 1, current->y + 1);

        for(i = sx; i <= ex; i++) {
            for(j = sy; j <= ey; j++) {
                neighbor = tiles[((j - 1) * 17) + i - 1];
                if(neighbor == current || !neighbor->walkable) continue;
                previous = current;
                if(false /* raytrace */) {

                } else {
                    cost = (current->x != neighbor->x || current->y != neighbor->y) ? 1.4 : 1;
                    g = current->g + cost;
                    h = euclidian(neighbor, end);
                    f = g + h;
                }

                if(std::find(open.begin(), open.end(), neighbor) != open.end() ||
                   std::find(closed.begin(), closed.end(), neighbor) != closed.end()) {
                    if(neighbor->f > f) {
                        neighbor->f = f;
                        neighbor->g = g;
                        neighbor->h = h;
                        neighbor->previousTile = current;
                    }
                } else {
                    neighbor->f = f;
                    neighbor->g = g;
                    neighbor->h = h;
                    neighbor->previousTile = current;
                    open.push_back(current);
                }
            }
        }

        closed.push_back(current);
        if(open.size() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        std::sort(open.begin(), open.end(), sortF());
        current = open[0];
        std::remove(open.begin(), open.end(), 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting. By the way, use a heap structure, is much better that sorting every iteration.

Comment: good point, i will probably switch to that, but i'd still like to figure this error out.

Comment: Please remove all code, that is not relevant for the sorting and then post the Error you get from that version of the code.

Comment: If you want to sort a vector of `X`, your comparator must accept two `X`s. If `X` is `T*`, your comparator must accept two `T*`s. This is normally done with something like `bool operator()(const T*, const T*)`.

Comment: @Javi V: Actually, heap data structures are usually very slow on modern CPUs. So as a first order of approximation, one should rather change the algorithm, so the data doesn`t have to stay ordered all the time.

Comment: @MikeMB can you give a reference for that? Are you telling me that sort n times a vector is faster that insert in a binary heap n times? Excuse me but I am skeptical. I work in path planning algorithms and never heard something like that.

Comment: @Javi V: What I wanted to say is that I'd first try to reduce the number of necessary sorts before giving up a vector, which is (in most cases) one of the best performing data structures. If thats not possible, then its worth a try. Probably my error was also to assume that you are talking about a datastructure with individually allocated nodes. Although he dosn't talk about heaps, there is a good talk from Chandler Carruth on cppcon2014 on the topic of algorithms and datastructures: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs

Comment: @MikeMB But in algorithms such Dijkstra (or A* which is the one I think OP is programming) to have a heap is a requirement. Otherwise, you would need to find the min over a vector at any iteration and I cannot think in a case this will be faster than just a regular heap. Anyway, thanks for the link, I will watch it!

Comment: @Javi V: You're probably right. I havn't sufficently analyzed the code / algorithm above. I'd still would like to see a performance comparison of the two versions. Is there a particular STL or boost data structure you would recommend?

Comment: @Evan Ward: Sorry for the somewhat OT discussion here.

Comment: @MikeMB usually for Dikjstra and A* the Fibonacci Heap is used. But in practice, since the number of nodes in the graph is not big enough (usually) the binary heap performs better. Therefore  `boost::heap::d_ary_heap` (with d=2) is probably the best option. It can be done with a single priority queue as well and usually it works even better but it is not then the classic algorithm. There are tons of discussion about this topic, specially in SO.

Comment: @Javi V: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I've some time. Btw.: boost::heap::d_ary_heap is apparently implemented in terms of a std::vector. As I said, my main mistake was to assume you'd be talking about a data structure with individually allocated nodes (like a std::list or std::map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** You didn't include your error messages, so the following answer is more or less based on view compiling:</sup>

#### `sortF()`, not `sortF`

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
    std::sort(open.begin(), open.end(), sortF);
                                             ^
```

You need an instance of `sortF`, not the type `struct sortF`. Either use `sortF()` to create a temporary object, or use a function instead of a functor:

```
bool sortF(const Tile& a, const Tile& b)
{
    return a.f > b.f;
}
```

#### `Tile*` vs `const Tile&`

You use `std::sort` on a `std::vector<Tile*>`, but your comparing function uses `const Tile&` as parameter. Either use `std::vector<Tile>` or correct the type in your function:

```
bool sortF(const Tile* a, const Tile* b)
{
    return a->f > b->f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the elements of the `std::vector` of type `Tile*`, the function that compares two items of the `std::vector` must take two `Tile*`s.

```
struct sortF
{
    bool operator()(Tile* ap, Tile* bp) const
    {
        return a->f > b->f;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely must change references to pointers in the comparer function. You didn't tell where exactly you got the error about comparison between pointer and integer, but I believe it happened on this line:

```
std::remove(open.begin(), open.end(), 0);
```

[std::remove()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) takes a value type of the container, not an index. What you wanted to do is probably

```
open.pop_front()
```

That said, this operation as well as sorting take quite a bit of time, and as Javi V commented, using heap structure is preferable here.